# What is the diffrence between closure return by function and generated locally in rust?

Tags: rust, closures

The following codes show two closures: c1, c2.
c1 is returned by a function, c2 is generated locally. c1 can not be sent to a thread. Why?

```rust
fn gen_closure() -> Box<dyn Fn(&str)> {
    return Box::new(|s: &str| {
        println!("gen_closure: {}", s);
    });
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = gen_closure();
    let c2 = Box::new(|s: &str| {
        println!("main_closure: {}", s);
    });

    /* `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str)` cannot be sent between threads safely
    the trait `Send` is not implemented for `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str)`
    required because of the requirements on the impl of `Send` for `Unique<dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str)>`
    required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:13:24: 15:6]` */
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        (c1)("c1");
    });

    /* This is okay */
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        (c2)("c2");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Rust (as in e.g. C++) every closure has its own anonymous type.

Since `c2` is a local, the compiler knows exactly what its *concete* type is, and thus can know all its traits, including that it's `Send` (because it closes over nothing that's `!Send`... since it's not closing over anything).

However `c1` is returned as `dyn Fn`, meaning as far as the compiler is concerned *the only trait it can rely on is `Fn`*. The compiler only has local visibility, and that's what you're telling it to rely on.

The way to make it sendable is to assert and guarantee that it is:

```rust
fn gen_closure() -> Box<dyn Fn(&str) + Send>
```

In that case, the caller can rely on this contract, and the callee will not compile if the returned function is not actually `Send` e.g.

```rust
fn gen_closure() -> Box<dyn Fn(&str) + Send> {
    let rc = std::rc::Rc::new(1);
    return Box::new(move |s: &str| {
        println!("gen_closure: {} {}", s, rc);
    });
}
```

=>

```
error[E0277]: `Rc<i32>` cannot be sent between threads safely
 --> src/main.rs:3:12
  |
3 |        return Box::new(move |s: &str| {
  |  _____________^________-
  | | ____________|
  | ||
4 | ||         println!("gen_closure: {} {}", s, rc);
5 | ||     });
  | ||_____-^ `Rc<i32>` cannot be sent between threads safely
  | |______|
  |        within this `[closure@src/main.rs:3:21: 5:6]`
  |
  = help: within `[closure@src/main.rs:3:21: 5:6]`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `Rc<i32>`
  = note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:3:21: 5:6]`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r str) + Send`
```

Comment: great, got it, thank you very much!

Comment: Great explanation, thanks. I will argue about the locality exlanation of why c2 is Send. It is Send because the type inferred by the compiler is a concrete type, and therefore it is known to be Send (or not). If you force it to be Box<dyn Fn(&str)>, then it will not be Send even though it is local.

Comment: @OzgurMurat if you force the type to be `Send` then you're explicitely erasing the concrete type, therefore the compiler can't know what traits implemented for it.

Answer (score 3):

To complement Masklinn's answer, I want to give another example:

If you change the return type to be `impl Fn(&str)`, then it will also work. Because the function will be instantiated for the concrete type, the returned type will be known to be `Send`.

```
fn gen_closure() -> impl Fn(&str) {
    return |s: &str| {
        println!("gen_closure: {}", s);
    };
}
```

Comment: Great! Your replenish is also very very useful.